# Returning arbitrary types from a function

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-fusion, boost-mpi

I'd like to return an arbitrary type from a function. The return type depends dynamically on a polymorphic function call. Foe example, the following reads values from CSV files with different number of columns,

```
struct File 
{
    virtual SOMETHING getTuple();
};

struct File1 : File
{
    SOMETHING getTuple()
    {   
        return std::tuple<int, double, string>();
    }    
};

struct File2 : File
{
    SOMETHING getTuple()
    {   
        return std::tuple<string, string>();
    }    
};

int main() 
{
    std::ifstream fs("file.csv");
      File2 f;
    BOOST_AUTO(tuple, f.getTuple())
    BOOST_AUTO(row, read(fs,tuple));
    BOOST_FOREACH(BOOST_TYPEOF(tuple) element , row )
    {
        for_each(element,print());
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};
```

How could I write the `getTuple()` signature to return different types based on which object is called?

### SOLUTION:

```
class File1
{
    std::ifstream ifs;
public:
    typedef boost::fusion::vector<int, double, std::string> tuple; 
    File1() : ifs("file1.csv") {}

    std::ifstream& getfs()
    {
        return ifs;
    }
};

class File2
{
    std::ifstream ifs;
public:
    typedef boost::fusion::vector<std::string, std::string> tuple; 
    File2() : ifs("file2.csv") {}

    std::ifstream& getfs()
    {
        return ifs;
    }
};

int main()
{
    File2 f;
    typedef File2::tuple tuple;

    BOOST_AUTO(x, read(f.getfs(),tuple()));
    BOOST_FOREACH(tuple e , x )
    {
        for_each(e,print());
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve that. The function signature needs to be determined at compile-time, so it cannot depend on the dynamic type of an object.

The closest you can do is to use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) for static polymorphism. That is, do the following:

```
template<class Derived>
struct FileBase 
{
    typename Derived::TupleType getTuple()
    {
        return typename Derived::TupleType();
    }
};


struct File1 : FileBase<File1>
{
   typedef std::tuple<int, double, string> TupleType;
};

struct File2 : FileBase<File2>
{
    typedef std::tuple<string, string>() TupleType; 
};
```

This would give the behaviour you wanted in the given example, but it won't work via a a runtime polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks for the CRTP tip. Unfortunately it ignores the fact that with CRTP the bodies of base class template member functions are only instantiated after the entire derived class declaration is known to the compiler so `TupleType` is unknown when `FileBase` is compiled. Please see my solution above which doesn't use CRTP. Does it look reasonable?

Comment: @user1626720 Sorry about that, I was unable to try the code at the moment of writing, so I'm not surprised there was an issue. Your solution does seem reasonable, assuming that you are not able to use C++11 (where the `auto` keyword and `tuple` would make your code much simpler).